# Doing operations on a subset of rows and storing the results in a different table - mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table that currently stores information such as latitude and longitude. The table also stores multiple records of the same user (i.e. same row) but stores different values (i.e. we have duplicate rows but with different values in their columns). I am trying to take the average of all the records for the same user (i.e the average of all the values stored in the duplicated rows) and store the resulting value in a single unique row in a different table.

Here is how the original table is structured (OldTable):

```
           creatorId        longitude   latitude    dutyCycleLevel
:ID[giA0CqQcx+(9kbuSKV==    -106.58341  52.115345   -3712
lXB+jIS)DN!CXmj>0(P8^]==    -106.6113   52.084724   -3480
lXB+jIS)DN!CXmj>0(P8^]==    -106.610886 52.084927   -3480
lXB+jIS)DN!CXmj>0(P8^]==    -106.61092  52.084885   -3480
```

Here is how the new table is structured (NewTable):

```
           creatorId    latitude    longitude   DutyCycle
:ID[giA0CqQcx+(9kbuSKV==    NULL    NULL    -3712
lXB+jIS)DN!CXmj>0(P8^]==    NULL    NULL    -3481
lXB+jIS)DN!CXmj>0(P8^]==    NULL    NULL    -3480
```

As you may notice, I still have a a duplicate creatorId field. That is because I am storing the values based on distinct DutyCycle values.

Here is the script that I tried to use but did not provide the desired result:

```
insert into db.NewTable(latitude)
select AVG(oldTable.latitude) from db.oldTable 
inner join NewTable on NewTable.dutyCycle = oldTable.dutyCycleLevel
group by dutyCycleLevel
```

As I have mentioned, I am trying to take the average latitude for every unique dutyCycle (as can be noticed in the original table) and store it as a unique averaged value in the NewTable in the same row as in the original table (i.e. the same dutyCycle row).

Any suggestions?

Comment: You want insert new rows from scracth or you want update exinsting   rowslike you have showd in in sample (newTable) ?

Comment: I have already imported all the distinct 'creatorId' and 'dutyCycleLevel' into the NewTable so yes, I have to update the rows now with new values.

Comment: Well then you should use the update query i provide in the posted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want update the new table

```
update NewTable
inner join OldTable on NewTabl.eCreatorId = OldTable.CreatorId
set latitude = avg(OldTable.latitude) 
group by OldTable.latitutude;
```

if you want insert from scratch

```
insert into db.NewTable(creatorId, longitude, latitude, dutyCycleLevel)
select creatorId, AVG(longitude), AVGlatitude), dutyCycleLevel
from db.oldTable 
group by creatorId, dutyCycleLevel
```

Comment: That helps. Thank you! 

On a side note, I realized that I could also insert everything when I create the table, which makes things a bit easier but of course, is a bit computationally expensive.

Comment: Yes is for this that i have posted the second query